# How to populate multiple textbox based on dropdown selection?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have to populate my 2 textboxes based on the dropdown value from a single table.

Here is my table structure:
[image: table-structure]

When I select the product name from the dropdown I want the 2 textboxes values to populate 1.sale_price 2.tax_amt. I have already populated the dropdown value from DB, please help me with the textboxes value.

**DROPDOWN:**

```
               <select name="select_services[]" class="form-control select_services">
                         <option value="">--SelectProduct--</option>
                        <?php
                        $sql= "SELECT * from  products where delete_status='0' ORDER BY id DESC";
                          $result=$conn->query($sql);
                       foreach ($result as $r_service) { ?>  
                            <option value="<?php echo $r_service['id'];?>"><?php echo $r_service['name'];?></option>
                       <?php } ?>
                       </select>
```

**Textboxes that I need to populate**

```
 <div class="col-sm-2">
                                           <input type="text" class="form-control" id="unit_price" name="unit_price[]" placeholder="Sale Price" required>
                                            </div>
                                            
                                           <div class="col-sm-2">
                                           <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tax" name="tax[]" placeholder="Tax" required>
                                            </div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
          $('div.mydiv').on("change",'select[name^="select_services"]',function(event){
            var currentRow=$(this).closest('.subdiv');
            var drop_services= $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url  : 'ajax_service.php',
                data : {drop_services:drop_services },
                success: function(data){
                    currentRow.find('input[name^="quantity"]').val(0);
                    currentRow.find('input[name^="unit_price"]').val(data);
                    var quantity =currentRow.find('input[name^="quantity"]').val();
                  var unitprice=currentRow.find('input[name^="unit_price"]').val();
                  var total = parseInt(quantity) * parseInt(unitprice);
                  currentRow.find('input[name^="total"]').val(total);
                   //var total=+currentRow.find('input[name^="total"]').val(total);
         // $('#subtotal').val(total);
    var sum = 0;
    $('.total').each(function() {
        if($(this).val()!='')
        {
            sum += parseInt($(this).val());
        }
        
    });
    
var sub = $('#subtotal').val(sum);
var fsub = $('#final_total').val(sum);
var tot_commi = 0;
                }
            });
            
        });
    </script>
```

**PHP: ajax_service.php**

```
<?php
include('connect.php');

if(isset($_POST['drop_services']))
  {
       $sql_service1 ="SELECT * FROM products WHERE id  = '".$_POST['drop_services']."'";
        $result1=$conn->query($sql_service1);  
        $service1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1);
        echo $service1['sale_price']; exit;
  }
?>
```

Comment: do you need to get the price every time you change the selection - do your prices change throughout the day?  It would be a lot easier to just add a data attribute to the selects and update the lot from the front end

Comment: yes but the price and tax amount should be changed when I select a product from the dropdown